# Is this a valid thing to do to this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, infinitesimals

Don't tell me how to solve it, but I've been trying to use the following equation to get r which is distance) as a function of t.

$$\frac{GMm}{r^2}= -ma$$

I've been working on it for about a year now and I think I may have made a breakthrough, but I'm not sure. Here's what I did.

$$\frac{GM}{r^2}=-a$$
$$\frac{GM}{r^2}=-\frac{dv}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dr}{dv} \dot{} \frac{GM}{r^2}=-\frac{dv}{dt}\dot{}\frac{dr}{dv}$$
$$\frac{dr}{dv} \dot{} \frac{GM}{r^2}=-\frac{dr}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dr}{dv} \dot{} \frac{GM}{r^2}=-v$$

This is really convenient because I haven't taken differential equations, and this gets rid of the second derivative. The only problem is I've read something somewhere about not be able to treat derivatives as fractions. Is this okay to do, and if so why?

Comment: Wait, what is your breakthrough...?

Comment: don't laugh. It's the part where I multiplied by dr/dv

Comment: Since $r=r(t)$ and $v=v(t)$ we can express $r$ as a function of $v$ so $\frac{dr}{dv}$ makes sense. You can of course multiply the equation with it. The next step is the chain-rule: $\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{dr}{dv}\frac{dv}{dt}$. The end result is correct, but I don't know if it will help much to solve the problem. Integrating the final equation just gives you energy conservation $1/2v^2 - GM/r = $const. which you already know (I assume - if not then using this equation will help to solve the equation).

Comment: OP did say *not* to tell him the answer.

Comment: @Winther The next thing I did was factor the work done and substitute one of the terms for a term involving time and distance ;)